# Replacing numbers in a list of lists with corresponding lines from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, linecache

I have a big text file like this (without the blank space in between words but every word in each line):

```
this

is

my

text

and

it

should

be

awesome

.
```

And I have also a list like this:

```
index_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8][9,10]]
```

Now I want to replace every element of each list with the corresponding index line of my text file, so the expected answer would be:

```
new_list = [[this, is, my, text, and],[it, should, be],[awesome, .]
```

I tried a nasty workaround with two for loops with a range function that was way too complicated (so I thought). Then I tried it with `linecache.getline`, but that also has some issues:

```py
import linecache

new_list = []

for l in index_list:
       for j in l:
             new_list.append(linecache.getline('text_list', j))
```

This does produce only one big list, which I don't want. Also, after every word I get a bad `\n` which I do not get when I open the file with `b = open('text_list', 'r').read.splitlines()` but I don't know how to implement this in my replace function (or create, rather) so I don't get `[['this\n' ,'is\n' , etc...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Just use a temp list and the append that to the main list. Also you can use `str.strip` to remove newline char.

**Ex:**

```
import linecache

new_list = []
index_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10]]
for l in index_list:
    temp = []   #Temp List
    for j in l:
        temp.append(linecache.getline('text_list', j).strip())
    new_list.append(temp)       #Append to main list.
```

Comment: Oh my god, BIG thanks to you! so i needed a temporary list in order to solve this, thanks, i learned something!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `iter` to do this as long as you `text_list` has exactly as many elements as `sum(map(len, index_list))`

```py
text_list = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'text', 'and', 'it', 'should', 'be', 'awesome', '.']

index_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10]]
text_list_iter = iter(text_list)
texts = [[next(text_list_iter) for _ in index] for index in index_list]
```

Output

```py
[['this', 'is', 'my', 'text', 'and'], ['it', 'should', 'be'], ['awesome', '.']]
```

But I am not sure if this is what you wanted to do. Maybe I am assuming some sort of ordering of index_list. The other answer I can think of is this list comprehension

```py
texts_ = [[text_list[i-1] for i in l] for l in index_list]
```

Output

```py
[['this', 'is', 'my', 'text', 'and'], ['it', 'should', 'be'], ['awesome', '.']]
```